# associate model to itself using a field in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I'm working on a model which is going to associate to itself multiple times using a key stored in a field. to declare it more specifically this is an example of my table with some rows:

```
id          name            association_id
------------------------------------------------------------------
33          item0           1111
34          item1           2222
35          item2           2222
36          item3           2222
37          item4           NULL
```

according to this data items named item1 to item3 are all associated to each other but not with item0 or item4.
the problem is that I don't know how to implement this association in CakePHP. It should be a hasMany but is it there possible to connect word with the same field (association_id) pointing to itself, not pointing to the primary key which is **id** here?
this association_id will be generated on the fly if needed to connect two or more items.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to normalize your table. In order to do that, you'd have to split this table like so:

```
associations:
id | name

items:
id | name | association_id
```

The model relationships would be as follows:

```
Item belongsTo Association
Association hasMany Item
```

If association_id is just some token in your table, then you don't need to create any extra relation. Just query the table with the grouping field in mind.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It was at first my option, but the associations doesn't really exist as an stand alone object, they exist only if items are connected to each other. and this id is going to be generated on demand and deleted on the fly, where no association exists.